# Polynomial has right inverse implies invertible?

Tags: polynomials, inverse

> If $p:\Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb R$ is a real polynomial such that $p$ has a right inverse $q$, does it follow that $p$ is invertible? That is, must $q$ also be a left inverse of $p$?

The question comes from working with the two functions

> $$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^3+\frac{3}{2}x\qquad\text{ and }\qquad g(x)=\sqrt[3]{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}+\sqrt[3]{x-\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

The algebra to show that $(f\circ g)(x)=x$ is straight-forward but showing $(g\circ f)(x)=x$  has been tricky with elementary algebra. I'm wondering if this more general result is true out of curiosity and also to avoid unnecessary computation.

Comment: If $g$ is surjective, then since $g(f(g(x)) = g(x)$, we have $g(f(y)) = y$ for all $y$.

Comment: @copper.hat Indeed, a section which is an epimorphism also is an isomorphism. But must a right inverse of a polynomial be a surjection?

Comment: Not necessarily. A right inverse must be injective, so it's sirjective iff that function is invertible (both on the left and right).

Answer (score 0):

If $p$ has a right inverse, then $p$ is surjective. For $p$ to even have a left inverse, it would also have to be injective, and if it is, $p$ is bijective and thus invertible.

To see if $p$ is injective, it suffices to show that $f$ is always increasing or always decreasing, which you can check using derivatives.

Comment: How would you use derivatives to demonstrate that a polynomial with a right inverse is necessarily injective?

Comment: You can check that the first derivative is always nonnegative or always nonpositive, and use the second derivative to rule out inflection points, I think.